# Should I use "of" or not?

Tags: grammar

These two statements are identical except that first one contains the preposition "of" after the word "understanding", while the second one doesn't:

> 1. "Gained an understanding of and had hands-on experience on Satellite Broadcasting and AM broadcasting.
> 2. "Gained an understanding and had hands-on experience on Satellite Broadcasting and AM broadcasting."

Is the version with "of" better than the version without it, or is it worse, or are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you're phrasing it as "an understanding", then you need to use "of". You should also change "on" to "in".

Gained an understanding of and had hands-on experience *in* [both] Satellite and AM broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: keep the ‘of’ and get rid of the ‘on’ by putting the object of the two actions on the first one.

"Gained an understanding of Satellite Broadcasting and AM broadcasting, and  had hands-on experience."

Also since  the hands-on experience is also a gain,

"Gained an understanding and hands-on experience of Satellite Broadcasting and AM broadcasting."  , putting some distance between the two ‘and.’